Flutter ListView.builder keep calling http when scrolling back and foward
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: 10,
  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
      child:  Hello()
    );
  },
),

How can I make Hello() only build once? I was using List.generate() and I saw that I had to use ListView.Builder() to make them build only once. But, it seems like it is not working. I can see that it is sending http requests as I scroll like List.generate().

How is the HTTP request being triggered? Is it within the Hello widget or elsewhere?

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class MyListView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyListViewState createState() => _MyListViewState();
}

class _MyListViewState extends State<MyListView> {
  Future<List<String>>? _futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _futureData = fetchData();
  }

  Future<List<String>> fetchData() async {
    // Simulate an HTTP request
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      return data.map((item) => item['title'] as String).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _futureData,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
          return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
        } else {
          final data = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                child: Text(data[i]),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: MyListView())));
}


You should not load the data from server in the build function, This is not the proper way.

Make a private function to load data:

Future<List<String>> _loadData () async {
    List<String> _fetched = [];

    // http request ...

    return _fetched;
  }


And a private variable to hold the data:
 List<String> _data = [];

Make sure you call get the data at the initState:


 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _data = _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

Ways to show the data:

Using FutureBuilder
Using .map function

